# Drivers for packet injection on the Intel Centrino(R) Advanced N 6205

Tags: backtrack, packet, aircrack-ng

I have an Intel Centrino(R) Advanced N 6205, running BackTrack 5 in VMWare.  I'm having trouble following the tutorial on aircrack-ng website, and I need to know what drivers to download to support packet injection.

Does anybody know if this card supports packet injections and, if so, how do I go about enabling that?

Comment: I've heard somewhere (but not yet verified) that these drivers are already included since BT 5 RC1. to be confirmed, i'm download it right now.